# Site-wide form with Symfony2?

Tags: forms, csrf, symfony

I have simple form at all site pages: username, password, [Sign In]

I tried to make with with simple HTML, but I get

```
The CSRF token is invalid. Please try to resubmit the form
```

Idea to make form in each action seems bad. What is the good practice of doing site-wide forms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do it this way:

First, I guess you have some base template file like layout.html.twig and all other pages extend it. Eg:

```
// Resources/views/layout.html.twig

<doc ... bla blah>
<title>My site</title>
...(js, css)...
<body>
    <div id="top">
        {% render url("site_wide_form") %}
    </div>


{% block content %}
{% endblock content %}
</body>
```

You need controller that will handle your form:

```
//Controller/SitewideController.php

/**
* @Route("/some/url/here", name="site_wide_form")
* @Template("yourbudle:folder:site_wide_form.html.twig")
*/
public function someAction()
{
    ..... your code for form, process submission etc ...
    return ["form"=>$form->createView()] ;
}
```

and template file:

```
// site_wide_form.html.twig

<form action="{{ path("site_wide_form") }}" method="post">
{{ form_widget(form) }}
</form>
```

That's it. Read this to understand render tag: http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/book/templating.html#embedding-controllers

Answer (score 0):

The CSRF token is missing. In your template (I assume you use Twig). You can tell Symfony2 to render all the remaining form elements using:

```
{{ form_rest(form) }}
```

Or you can render just the CSRF token:

```
{{ form_row(form._token) }}
```

Comment: Variable "form" does not exist in ....html.twig at line 74
I understand that this is because I make pure HTML, not creating form. But it seems wrong to create form object in each action.